# Get selected state of Angular Material radio button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material `mat-table` with columns for checkboxes and rows,  using Material components for each. I can get the selected state of the checkbox with `row.checked`, as show below. How can I find the selected state for the radio button?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="selectCheck">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="row[columnCompare] != valueCompare? 'styled-cell' : null">
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="row.selected">
      <mat-radio-button (change)="radioSelected(row)"></mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="selectRadio">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-radio-button (change)="radioSelected(row)"></mat-radio-button>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

TS

```
public radioSelected(row): void {
  //row.checked is undefined here
}
```

Comment: No shortage of documentation for the library: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="selectCheck">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="row[columnCompare] != valueCompare? 'styled-cell' : null">
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="row.selected">
      <mat-radio-button (change)="radioSelected(row)"></mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="selectRadio">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="row.selected" (change)="radioSelected(row)">
      <mat-radio-button [value]="true"></mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

TS

```
public radioSelected(row): void {
  console.log(row.selected);
}
```

Comment: does `mat-radio-button` have a checked property? or is it selected? I'm getting undefined for row.checked

Comment: yes `[checked]="true/false"` will work. See this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibrkvq

Comment: I don't know why but row.checked continues to return `undefined`

public radioSelected(row): void {
    //row.checked is undefined here
  }

Comment: Can you create the stackblitz so that i can see what is wrong in this case?

Comment: check the  stackblitz for your undefined issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibrkvq

Comment: I think I have got it. So why do we need to set `[value]=true`?

Comment: it's important because `ngModel` work with value. you have to set value. it's not required to set it true. You can use any value here then you will get the save value on row.selected. Like `[value]="'somevalue'"` then `row.selected` will give you `somevalue`

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for the help! Very much appreciated.